# Applescript to duplicate files from Resources, interacting with Finder, Capture One Pro

Tags: applescript

I have an Applescript app that copies a specific **.txt** file and a blank **Capture One Pro .session** from the app bundle resources - to new names and locations selected by the user, that Capture One (id C1PR) will then open.

The script is working but I'm still kinda new to coding, so I was hoping there's a better / neater way to write this. 
Specifically if the 4 x separate **'display dialogs'** and **'choose folders'** could be replaced by 2x **"choose file name with prompt"s**?

I haven't worked out how to use a **choose file name** prompt and then create that folder, while also retaining the name input to make a "newJobName" or "seshName" variables for use later on.

Would really appreciate any advice on cleaning this up, and any hints about the using the "Choose File Name" prompt from the user input scripting additions. Thanks!

Here is the current script.

```
set logoIcon to alias ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Ourlogo.icns")
set bundleResources to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:"
set defaultLocation to (path to desktop) as alias
set newJobname to text returned of (display dialog "TODAY'S JOB NAME:" with title "OurCompany New Job" default answer "Job-2018-00-00" with icon logoIcon)
set newLoc to (choose folder with prompt "CHOOSE SAVE LOCATION FOR TODAY'S JOB:" default location defaultLocation)

tell application "Finder"
    set newJobDirectory to make new folder at newLoc with properties {name:newJobname}
    set getJobBrief to file "job_brief_template.rtf" of (bundleResources as alias) --getting job brief from bundle and renaming to match today's job after duplicating
    duplicate getJobBrief to newJobDirectory
    set name of document file "job_brief_template.rtf" of newJobDirectory to newJobname & ".rtf"
    make new folder at newJobDirectory with properties {name:"Raw Folder"} --creating standard folders required for our daily jobs
    make new folder at newJobDirectory with properties {name:"Mark Ups"}
    make new folder at newJobDirectory with properties {name:"Resources"}
    make new folder at newJobDirectory with properties {name:"JPGS"}
    make new folder at newJobDirectory with properties {name:"No Retouching"}

    set seshName to text returned of (display dialog "TODAY'S CAPTURE SESSION NAME:" default answer newJobname with icon logoIcon) --usually the same as the newJobName but need to give user a choice to ammend it.
    set the clipboard to {text:seshName, Unicode text:seshName} --setting job name to clipboard in case Capture Session doesn't work.

    set targetSesh to (choose folder with prompt "CHOOSE LOCATION FOR TODAY'S CAPTURE SESSION:" default location defaultLocation)
    set newSeshDirectory to make new folder at targetSesh with properties {name:seshName}
    make new folder at newSeshDirectory with properties {name:"Capture"} --creating standard Capture One Pro session folders
    make new folder at newSeshDirectory with properties {name:"Selects"}
    make new folder at newSeshDirectory with properties {name:"Output"}
    make new folder at newSeshDirectory with properties {name:"Trash"}
    set getSeshDoc to file "session.cosessiondb" of (bundleResources as alias) --getting blank session from bundle and renaming to match today's job after duplicating
    duplicate getSeshDoc to newSeshDirectory
    set name of document file "session.cosessiondb" of newSeshDirectory to seshName & ".cosessiondb"
    set openSesh to result --variable to tell Capture One application to open

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

`choose file name` returns a `file` specifier (file URL) which can easily converted to a POSIX path.

This is a *cleaned up* version which uses the shell command `mkdir` to create all folders in one line.

```
set bundleResources to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:"
set defaultLocation to path to desktop
set newJobLocation to (choose file name with prompt "TODAY'S JOB NAME:" default name "Job-2018-00-00" default location defaultLocation) as text

do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of newJobLocation & "/{'Raw Folder','Mark Ups',Resources,JPGS,'No Retouching'}"
tell application "Finder"
    set jobName to name of folder newJobLocation
    set getJobBrief to file "job_brief_template.rtf" of folder bundleResources
    duplicate getJobBrief to folder newJobLocation
end tell

set newSeshLocation to (choose file name with prompt "TODAY'S CAPTURE SESSION NAME:" default name "Job-2018-00-00" default location defaultLocation) as text
do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of newSeshLocation & "/{Capture,Selects,Output,Trash}"
tell application "Finder"
    set seshName to name of folder newSeshLocation
    set getSeshDoc to file "session.cosessiondb" of folder bundleResources
    set duplicatedFile to duplicate getSeshDoc to folder newSeshLocation
    set name of duplicatedFile to seshName & ".cosessiondb"
    set the clipboard to {text:seshName, Unicode text:seshName}
end tell
set openSesh to result --variable to tell Capture One application to open
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much neater! 

I am however, getting a -1728 error on the "set jobName to name of folder" part of line 6. Specifically the word 'name'. Invalid object reference. 
Any suggestions? Thanks again!